# Using function argument as part of a constant expression - gcc vs clang

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, constexpr, constant-expression

Consider the following code snippet:

```
template <bool> struct B { };

template <typename T>
constexpr bool pred(T t) { return true; } 

template <typename T>
auto f(T t) -> decltype(B<pred(t)>{})
{
}
```

- clang++ *(trunk)* compiles the code
- g++ *(trunk)* fails compilation with the following error:

  ```
  src:7:34: error: template argument 1 is invalid
  auto f(T t) -> decltype(B<pred(t)>{})
                                  ^

  src:7:34: error: template argument 1 is invalid
  src:7:34: error: template argument 1 is invalid
  src:7:34: error: template argument 1 is invalid
  src:7:34: error: template argument 1 is invalid
  src:7:34: error: template argument 1 is invalid
  src:7:25: error: invalid template-id
  auto f(T t) -> decltype(B<pred(t)>{})
                          ^

  src:7:36: error: class template argument deduction failed:
  auto f(T t) -> decltype(B<pred(t)>{})
                                      ^

  src:7:36: error: no matching function for call to 'B()'
  src:1:24: note: candidate: 'template<bool <anonymous> > B()-> B<<anonymous> >'
  template <bool> struct B { };
                          ^

  src:1:24: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
  src:7:36: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter '<anonymous>'
  auto f(T t) -> decltype(B<pred(t)>{})
                                      ^
  ```

  [**live example on godbolt.org**](https://godbolt.org/g/Xjjcwc)

---

Even though g++'s diagnostic is misleading, I assume that the problem here is that `t` is not a *constant expression*. Changing the code to...

```
decltype(B<pred(T{})>{})
```

...fixes the compilation error on g++: [**live example on godbolt.org**](https://godbolt.org/g/F4vxAX)

---

What compiler is behaving correctly here?

Comment: Why is there no return statement in your `f` function?

Comment: @YSC don't be a nitpick :)

Comment: If you actually instantiate `f` clang also complains.

Comment: @Rakete1111 It depends with what you instantiate `f`.

Comment: @Rakete1111 Neither do I, but `f(std::integral_constant<int, 0>{})` is accepted by `clang`...

Comment: @Holt Ah a `constexpr` conversion operator :P Didn't think of that

Comment: I think your question is very related to: *"Is `auto f(std::integral_constant<int, 0> t) -> std::integral_constant<int, t>;` valid?"* (i.e., can you use a function argument as a constant expression in some cases).. clang accepts it, gcc does not. If this is valid, this means that your template is valid for some `T`, and so clang would be right to not throw errors, otherwise, gcc would be right.

Comment: I think the code as given is ill-formed because of the [lvalue-to-rvalue conversion](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#2.7) in initializing the parameter of `pred`.  Unfortunately, having `pred` accept a reference does not change either compiler's answer, so no confirmation there.

Comment: Weird... if you call one `constexpr` function from another `constexpr` function and you pass input arguments, entire call tree is treated as `constexpr`. But when you try to instantiate template, it does not work. Looks not consistent to me.

Comment: I think it is GCC's bug to treat function parameter an invalid template argument in **trailing return type**, since it compiles for [this code](https://godbolt.org/g/YuDKJw).

Comment: @DavisHerring Initializing may not invoke lvalue-to-rvalue conversion. For example, when initializing a class, it simply invoke the corresponding constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**GCC is wrong.** There is no rule that prevents using a function's parameters in a constant expression in this way.

However, you cannot use the *value* of the parameter in such a context, and the set of types `T` for which `f` is callable is quite restricted. To see why, we need to consider what constructs will be evaluated when evaluating the expression `pred(t)`:

```
// parameters renamed for clarity
template <typename U>
constexpr bool pred(U u) { return true; } 

template <typename T>
auto f(T t) -> decltype(B<pred(t)>{});
```

The evaluation semantics for the call `pred(t)` are as follows:

1. copy-initialize `pred`'s parameter `u` from `f`'s parameter `t`
2. evaluate the body of `pred`, which trivially creates a `bool` value `true`
3. destroy `u`

So, `f` is only callable for types `T` for which the above only involves constructs that are valid during constant evaluation (see [[expr.const]p2](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#2) for the rules). The requirements are:

- `T` must be a literal type
- copy-initialization of `u` from `t` must be a constant expression, and in particular, must not perform an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion on any member of `t` (because their values are not known), and must not name any reference member of `t`

In practice, this means that `f` is callable if `T` is an empty class type with a defaulted copy constructor, or if `T` is a class type whose copy constructor is `constexpr` and does not read any members of its argument, or (strangely) if `T` is `std::nullptr_t` (although [clang currently gets the `nullptr_t` case wrong](https://godbolt.org/z/r58fsL)).

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is expecting a parameter in that context because it needs to evaluate the full (template overloaded) function type. Given the implementation of pred, any value would work in that location. Here it is binding the f parameter's template type to the argument.
The g++ compiler appears to be making a simplifying assumption that a template `constexpr` function will somehow be altered by any parameters unless they are also `const`, which, as you've demonstrated, and clang agrees, is not necessarily the case.

It all comes down to how deep inside the function implementation the compiler goes to mark the function as non-const due to non-const contribution to the return value.

Then there is the question of whether the function is instantiated and requires the compiler to actually compile the code vs performing template parsing which, at least with g++, appears to be a different level of compilation.

Then I went to the standard and they kindly allow the compiler writer to make exactly that simplifying assumption and the template function instantiation should only work for `f<const T>` or `f <const T&>`

> constexpr` functions must have: each of its parameters must be
>   LiteralType

So the template code should compile but fail if instantiated with a non-const T.

Comment: These are high level generalisations based upon experience only.
I generally don't go digging around inside C++ compiler parsers.It can be bad for one's health. ;)

Comment: I'd be tempted to try mixing in remove_const<T> but I've already dug into this enough I think...

Answer (score -1):

`t` is not constexpr value, this mean `pred(t)` is not constexpr too.
You can't use it in `B<pred(t)>` because this need constexpr.

This version compile correctly:

```
template <bool> struct B { };

template <typename T>
constexpr bool pred(T t) { return true; } 

template <typename T, T t>
auto f() -> decltype(B<pred(t)>{})
{
}
```

https://godbolt.org/g/ydbj1X

Another valid code is:

```
template <typename T>
auto f(T t) -> decltype(pred(t))
{
}
```

This is because you do not evaluate `pred(t)` only you get type information.
`B<pred(t)>` need evaluation of `pred(t)` other wise you will get `B<true>` or `B<false>`, for any normal value you can't to this.

`std::integral_constant<int, 0>{}` can work in Clang case is probably because its value build in as part of type and always is same. If we change code a bit:

```
template <typename T>
auto f(T t) -> decltype(B<pred(decltype(t){})>{})
{
    return {};
}
```

both Clang and GCC compile it, in case `std::integral_constant`, both `t` and `decltype(t){}` have always same value.

Comment: The value of `t` may not be evaluated. You can see [this example](https://godbolt.org/g/YuDKJw).

Comment: @xskxzr I add bit more to answer to answer you question.